# Use default doctype filters on custom Dashboard Chart Source

Tags: frappe, frappe-charts

I'm trying to setup a new dashboard chart, with a "custom" dashboard chart source. My problem is that I'm apparently unable to get the default Doctype filters for my chart, even if it concerns a single doctype (defined in the `.json` file).
What I call "default Doctype filters" are the ones you can find in the list view. Those filters allow user to filter the Doctype depending on each field, which is very convenient.

[Screeshot with a "custom" chart type :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svq8Q.jpg)

[Screenshot with another chart type :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSy0n.jpg)

Do someone have an idea on how to setup those default Doctype filters ?
Thank you !

It seems that those default filters are disabled for custom chart source, apparently no matter if the Doctype is defined inside the chart source `.json` file. I mean, you can setup your own filters in the `.js` file, but it will be quite boring if the only goal is to reproduce the default Doctype filters. There is no documentation about it...